# system.web.webPages.razor keeps adding itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, web-config

I added a few nuget packages to my project to test. Now when I run it works fine but when I try to publish to the web server I get the following error:

> > Error       Unrecognized configuration section
> >     system.web.webPages.razor C:....\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\views\web.config

What I have tried:
Removing the entries, cleaning, close/reopen VS, and a reboot.

Even if I remove the entry physically, every time I republish it comes back.

**Edit 1** This is only an issue at Publishing. On normal compile and debug it works fine.

Comment: Try and delete the package folder's data, clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: @MasoudDarvishian Tried that.... still not working.